# mvc3 grid with good functionalities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, grid

I am searching for a asp.net + c# + mvc3 grid where i can do below actions

1. display items
2. link to item to show its description in new page
3. sorting
4. paging
5. Add check boxes to each item in grid and a button after grid to update selected items
6. ability to add drop down list in grid and do operations based on selections

Could some one suggest a good tutorial or plugin or some thing which would be helpful to me ??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Telerik MVC controls.  You should be able to do all of those with their grid (6 may be tricky, but it might be able to be done with a template column).

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx

Comment: looking for a free one. I think telerik grid is commercial.

Comment: You can download the open source version of the Telerik controls for free, you just don't get any direct support with them (you can still post on the forums, or here).

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/download.aspx